# Debugger wrong on unset __block BOOL variable?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, xcode7, objective-c-blocks

Just curious here, is this a debugger bug, or by design that I am not yet aware of.
The `_block`-ed variable is evaluated as `false` in code, but the debugger states it is `true`.

The code is run right in application:didFinishLaunching... method. Not in a block or anything.

What is going on?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is that code inside a *block*?

Comment: Hi, trojanfoe. No, it is not, I have edited the question.

Comment: What is more interesting - if you declare *foo* as NSInteger, it doesn't show this dependency on __block. However, using char type will be affected. While debug shows 128 value, NSLog prints -128.

Comment: If cast BOOL foo to int in debug watch expression, you'll see, that it has value of 128. However, YES is has corresponding value of 1.